# Ошибка при установке библиотеки через pip

Tags: python, pip

При попытке установить какую либо библиотеку с помощью команды `pip install [package name]` пишет `Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable.` Сама же библиотека устанавливается не в `C:\Program Files\Python39\Lib\site-packages` (где и был установлен питон), а вместо этого создается новая папка `%AppData%\Roaming\Python39\Lib\site-packages.` Как итог некорректно функционируют установленные библиотеки. Как исправить данную ошибку?

PyCharm отказывается импортировать библиотеки, хотя видит их:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Ответы на [этот вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59997065/pip-python-normal-site-packages-is-not-writeable) не решили проблему.

Comment: Я бы попробовал от администратора пакеты ставить. Такое впечатление, что прав не хватает ставить туда, где сейчас всё лежит.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте проверить path самого питона в вашем IDE. Если вы делаете данную процедуру через терминал самого IDE, есть вероятность, что в этом и заключается проблемы.

Лучше зайдите в консоль и напишите команду python, посмотрите той ли версией вы пользуетесь, либо перейдите в директорию питона в консоли, и там попробуйте сделать pip install.

Если ничего из вышеперечисленного не поможет, установите библиотеку как получиться, и из той директории перенесите нужные файлы библиотеки в python директорию, которую использует ваш IDE.

Comment: Если делать pip install из директории питона, библиотека все равно устанавливается в %AppData%\Roaming\Python. Попробовал перетащить файлы установленных библиотек в директорию, где установлен питон. В итоге pip list корреткно выдает эти библиотеки, но PyCharm почему то их не видит :(

Comment: Сейчас ради интереса написал pip list в консоли в самом PyCharm. Абсурд в том что оно корректно показывает все установленные библиотеки, но при импорте выдает ошибку, якобы они не установлены

Comment: А path питона в pycharm проверили? Если да то попробуйте другой IDE, мб проблема в нем

Comment: И вообще в pyCharm ведь можно в самом иде установить библиотеку без pip install, попробуйте так

Answer (score 0):

python -m pip install --upgrade pip

В терминале наберите, обновится.

Также сегодня было.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: При обновлении pip устанавливается опять же в директорию %AppData%\Roaming\Python39\Lib\site-packages, а в Program Files остается оригинальный pip

Answer (score 0):

Еще один из вариантов установки новой библиотеки в PyCharm – Preferences - Project: projectname - Python Interpreter. Выведет список всех установленных библиотек и при нажатии на "+" можно найти и выбрать ту, которую хотите установить.